# In Flash Builder 4.6: Displaying data from an Object in an ArrayCollection as a label

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have an object containing 3 strings, saved in an ArrayCollection.

```
package valueObjects
{
    public class User
    {
        public var rowid:String;
        public var userID:String;
        public var username:String;
    }      
}
```

saved to an ArrayCollection named "logins"

I am struggling to display individual entries from this. I would have thought `<s:Label text="{logins.username}" />` would do the trick, but apparently not, this just throws an error and  `<s:Label text="{logins}" />` just displays `[object User]`

I'm pretty new to Flash Builder and I am struggling to get my head around this.

Thanks

Comment: Read on `ItemRenderer`. Basically you render the data using it, as it has a `data` object that relates to the data. Very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to manually assign the first object's username as value to label property
you can do {logins.getItemAt(0).username} but that's not safe you can have null pointer sometime, so better assign manually..

Comment: Thats great, in this specific context there is only item and is only being accessed after it is definitely assigned through a login form on a separate state. I assume it is reasonably safe to not manually assign it this way as it is impossible to access this state without first populating the array.

Comment: if there is only one item, i don't think you should save in arraycollection or even array, just save it as your User object and assign UserObject.username to your label

Answer (score 0):

A more advanced approach to avoid null pointers

```
<Label text="{logins.length > 0 ? logins.getItemAt(0).username : Alert.show("There are + {logins.length} + Individuals")}" />
```